# Counterexample to an quasicircle

Tags: complex-analysis

currently I am trying to understand the definition of an quasicircle that is given via the Ahlfors condition, i.e. let $\Gamma$ is a Jordan curve then if for all finite points $z_1,z_2 \in \Gamma$ we can find $C > 0$ such that one has
$$
|z_1-z| + |z-z_2| \leq C |z_1-z_2|,
$$
where $z$ lies on the subarc joining $z_1$ and $z_2$ of smalles diameter. Now I believe that I miss something obvious in the following counterexample.

Let $\Gamma = \{x+iy \in \mathbb C : x \geq 0 \text{ and } y = \pm x^2 \}$ and choose $z_1 = x+ix^2$ and $z_2=x-ix^2$ then obviously the left side is of order $x^2$ but I don't see why the left side should be bounded below by at least $x$ geometrically. I thought that the smalles $z$ that minimizes the distance would at least give $x^2$ on the left side but according to Ohli Lehto's book this should be at least $x$ such that as $x \to 0$ one sees that $\Gamma$ is indeed not a quasicircle.

Comment: **Ahlfors**, not "Ahlfons."

Answer (score 0):

The left hand side can be much larger than $x^2$, when $x$ is small.  That is, at the point $z=0$, the left hand side is more than $2x$, which is much greater than the right hand side of $2Cx^2$, for small $x$.  So this is not a quasicircle under your original definition in the first paragraph either.